# How to export bookmarks out of Opera (Stable 44.0.2510.1159) on Windows 10

Tags: browser, bookmarks, opera, export

I am using Opera (Stable 44.0.2510.1159) in a laptop with Windows 10 operating system. Now, my problem is within the bookmark. I want to export my bookmarks in the said browser but I didn't find a way how to export bookmarks. Yesterday, I tried to find some solution, I do the following :

1. I open the **Speed Dial** click the heart icon (bookmark tab) at the left side. It open bookmarks page but I only see different views, adding folder and a check box with a label **"Shows the bookmark bar"**.
2. I press the Opera menu located at the top left corner of my browser. It open a list down of it's following menu or options. Then I hover the heart icon with a label bookmark. Then it open its sub-menu that contain only the following **'Show all bookmarks'**, **'Show bookmarks bar'**, **'Add to bookmarks'**, and **'My Folders'**.
3. I press the Opera menu located at the top left corner of my browser, click the **setting**. Then click on **Browser** scroll slowly and press the button **'Import bookmarks and setting'** but nothing.
4. Then take another search and trial **More Tools** and **Developer Menu**. Then I'm done. I got nothing.

I hope you help me about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong this one should help you.
[Import/Export Addon for Opera.](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/bookmarks-import-export/?display=en)

This extension allows you to backup & share bookmarks with Chrome,
Opera, Opera Classic, Firefox, Vivaldi and most other modern browsers.

Import & Export will export everything including "Speed Dial" & "Bookmarks Bar",
as it's using a documented bookmarks API called "chrome.bookmarks.getTree".

Answer (score 0):

Opera introduced the option to export bookmarks directly from opera version 47. so i suggest you to update the browser to the latest version.

However there are ways to export bookmarks directly from the current version too. **No Need to install any add-ons or 3rd party apps**

I don't know how to include this youtube video here. So please check the video link : [Export Opera bookmarks in Versions (41,42,43,44,45,46)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ5BoUKAyAE)

Also

Check out this article to know
[Exporting opera bookmarks to Chrome , to .html file](http://www.techisher.com/export-opera-bookmarks-chrome-others-mac-windows/)